# Need an Expert Opinion on Kinect

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am going to buy a **Microsoft Kinect** for the following reasons & Purposes

1. It is Cheap
2. i need to do some series of experiments using it with **iRobot Create**.
3. these experiments include Localization Algorithms like SLAM , Particle Filters etc.
4. for these reasons i need to get the range data from the Environment

**So here is my Question**

5. Is Kinect alone enough to sense range data or can it even take range data.
6. I have done some search over Google and i see people at MIT and others using    Kinect with Laser Range finders.

So tell me if its enough alone as a sensing device for range data or do i need something else with it
Note:Buying a **Laser range finder** is not possible for me as it costs more than **1000$**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49998/need-an-expert-opinion-on-kinect/) by [Neo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2306/neo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While the Kinect is a great sensor it has some serious drawbacks that need to be considered when it has to act as the only source of range data.

- The Kinect does not work well in bright Sunlight, as there is too much IR light comming in.
- Especially when using for fake-laser data the field of view is very small (only about 60 degree). So there have to be enough depth features and no clean walls, otherwise the scanmatching becomes very inaccurate.
- At ranges higher than about 2.5 meters the depth resolution becomes quite rough and the noise in measurements increases significantly.

If you can prepare your environment according to these points it might work well. However some algorithms that purely rely on high fov laser data like for example [Hector SLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam) will most likely still perform poor.

I suggest you read some of the questions and answers here to the topics of Kinect and fake laser. That will give you a good impression of the problems and limitations that will arise.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4